# Clear an object with a new object?

Tags: c++, variables, swap

I have:

```
MyClass myObject1( var1, var2 );
myObject1.someMethod(); //> Changes the interal state of the object
```

Now at some point I want to assign to `myObject1` a "clean" object of type `MyClass`. Something like:

```
myObject1 = MyClass( otherVar1, otherVar2 );
```

Without using pointers (and/or `unique_ptr`) is there any fast/efficient way to do it?

Comment: What means fast? With your example all is depends on constructor of MyClass and on operator = of MyClass.

Comment: Does `MyClass` use pointers to chunks of data that are expensive to copy? If so, implement a cheap swap funciton (and a move copy constructor for C++11).

Comment: You are not answering my question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Point 1**. Don't worry about performance until you have data from your profiler indicating that you should. Doing otherwise is called *premature optimization*, and it's a bad thing. Choose the simplest design first.

**Point 2**. In C++11, you can write a move assignment operator for `MyClass`, if that makes sense in your case (hard to say without knowing the definition of `MyClass`).

However, **an even better idea** would be to use RAII wrappers such as `unique_ptr` as members of your class, and let the compiler-generated move assignment operator do a member-wise move and delegate the work to the move assignment operator of your members. Then, the move assignment operator of your `unique_ptr` would take care of doing The Right Thing.

This way you would not have to bother following the Rule of Three, Rule of Five, or whatnot, you would get optimal performance, and (as a bonus) exception-safety. *Avoid defining your own special member functions*, and get used to follow the [**Rule of Zero**](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

[As mentioned by juanchopanza in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958260/clear-an-object-with-a-new-object#comment24489577_16958317), in C++03 you could provide a no-throw `swap()` function - but again, that may or may not help depending on the definition of your class.

Comment: A cheap, no throw `swap` could be a good C++03 alternative to the move constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Correct, I added that to the answer. Thank you!